# trouble in getting dynamic id`s for datepicker

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-datepicker

i want to generate a dynamic id of my datepicker. below jquery function shows the datetimepicker as the id is defined as static.

```
    $(function () {
    var dates = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_gvdLCStatus_txtInvoiceDate_0").datepicker(
    {
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        defaultDate: '+1w',
        changeMonth: false,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        showOn: 'both',
        buttonImage: 'Images/calendar_month.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            var option = this.id == "ContentPlaceHolder1_gvdLCStatus_txtInvoiceDate_0" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $(this).data("datepicker");
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings);
            dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
        }
    });
});
```

I want to generate a dynamic ID for the DatePicker. and How that i`ve tried various time but couldn`t find the actual way of doing.Thanks.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvdLCStatus" runat="server" DataKeyNames="LCID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4" EmptyDataText="No Record Found" CssClass="mGrid"
                    OnPageIndexChanging="gvdLCStatus_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="gvdLCStatus_RowCommand"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvdLCStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="gvdLCStatus_RowDataBound"
                    OnRowCreated="gvdLCStatus_RowCreated">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="test" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LC Number">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LCID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                <a href="#" onclick="linkbtnTest('<%# "#"+Eval("LCNumber") %>')">
                                    <%# Eval("LCNumber") %></a>
                                <%-- <div id='<%# Eval("ShipmentID") %>' style="display: none;">
                        </div>--%>
                                <div id='<%# Eval("LCNumber") %>' style="display: none;">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="gvShipmentStatus" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ShipmentID"
                                        OnRowCommand="gvShipmentStatus_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvShipmentStatus_RowDataBound"
                                        CssClass="mGrid">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceNumber" HeaderText="Invoice Number" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceDate" HeaderText="Invoice Date" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="BLNumber" HeaderText="B/L Number" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="BLDate" HeaderText="B/L Date" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="VesselName" HeaderText="Vessel Name" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="VoyageNumber" HeaderText="Voyage Number" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DueDate" HeaderText="Due Date" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractedShipmentSchedule" HeaderText="Shipment Schedule" />
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgShipmentDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# isDelete_img(Session["isAdmin"].ToString()) %>'
                                                        Enabled='<%# isDelete(Session["isAdmin"].ToString()) %>' CommandName="DeleteShipmentRecord"
                                                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ShipmentID") %>' AlternateText="DeleteShipmentRecord"
                                                        OnClientClick="return confirm_delete();" Style='<%# delete_style(Session["isAdmin"].ToString()) %>' />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <%--                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgShipmentEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png"
                                                CommandName="EditShipmentRecord" ImageAlign="Middle" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ShipmentID") %>'
                                                AlternateText="EditShipmentRecord" OnClientClick='linkbtnTest(<%# Eval("ShipmentID) %>)' />
                                                    --%>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="EditShipmentRecord"
                                                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ShipmentID")+":"+Eval("LCStatusID")%>'>
                                                        <%--<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ShipmentID") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>--%> <img src="Images/edit.png" alt="Edit" />
                                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </div>
                                <%--</div>--%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractNumber" HeaderText="Contract Number" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Qty" HeaderText="Quantity" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <a href="#" onclick="linkbtnTest('<%# "#"+Eval("LCID")%>')">Add Shipment Status</a>
                                <div id='<%# Eval("LCID") %>' style="display: none;">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="td_records" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                                                Invoice Number
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="td_records" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                                                Invoice Date (dd/mm/yyyy)
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="td_records" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                                                B/L Number
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="td_records" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                                                B/L Date (dd/mm/yyyy)
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtInvoiceNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtInvoiceDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBLNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBLDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="td_records" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                                                VesselName
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="td_records" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                                                VoyageNumber
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="td_records" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                                                DueDate (dd/mm/yyyy)
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="td_records" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                                                ShipmntSchedule (dd/mm/yyyy)
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtVesselName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtVoyageNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDueDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtShipmntSchedule" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitShipment" runat="server" Text="Submit" CommandName="Select"
                                                    OnCommand="btnSubmitShipment_Command" CssClass="btnSubmitCSS" />
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnResetShipmentRecord" runat="server" Text="Reset" CssClass="btnSubmitCSS" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# isDelete_img(Session["isAdmin"].ToString()) %>'
                                    Enabled='<%# isDelete(Session["isAdmin"].ToString()) %>' CommandName="DeleteRecord"
                                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("LCID") %>' AlternateText="DeleteRecord" OnClientClick="return confirm_delete();"
                                    Style='<%# delete_style(Session["isAdmin"].ToString()) %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png" CommandName="EditRecord"
                                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("LCID") %>' AlternateText="EditRecord" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I do not understand what is the problem and what is your question.

Comment: the problem is i only want to know how do i dynamically generate an id for a datepicker i.e
var dates = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_gvdLCStatus_txtInvoiceDate_0").datepicker

Comment: what happens here that, because of defining id statically, my datepickers show on to the jquery-dialog but when i open a dynamic jquery modal- dialog, the timepicker is not shown.

Comment: Do you have a live version of it ?

Comment: what do you mean by live version @Aristos

Comment: The page live on web, on a url to see what javascript error did you get, how the page is rendered, what ids find whats not..

Comment: @Aristos No, well, did you understand what i`m trying to express? English is not my native language so sorry if it troubles.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you may use such selector:

```
var dates = $("[id*='txtInvoiceDate']", "#<%= gvdLCStatus.ClientID %>")​
```

But better consider to set CssClass property on textboxes and use class selector

Comment: Not working, and due to this, the modal dialog doesnt even gets open. :/

Comment: When you execute this script?

Comment: yeah.. when i copied yours, my dialog doesnt even get opened.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you select by id? Why don't you go with class name? $('.datebox').dateTimepicker(...

Comment: As my gridview is bind from the database, the record count gets updated. i dont have a single record into my grid instead multiple records, so, for each record there will be a jquery dialog. so, when the user opens the dialog, i want to have a datepicker in that dialog which doesnt show when the gridview gets bind with more than 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

i found an alternate of validating it with asp.net required field validators. No other option was there and had to maintain the time constraint.

Thanks Guys.